# How to reverse an array in JavaScript without Array.prototype.reverse?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I try to reverse an array but without the `reverse` function.

Like you see I try to decrement the length of the array `num=(tab.length-i)-1`, so it works. But when I try to add `tab[i]=tab[num]`, it works but the value push inside `tab[i]` is random `[ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]`.

Do you have any idea why ?

```
const tab=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

let num=0

for(let i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
    num=(tab.length-i)-1
    console.log(num)
    tab[i]=tab[num]
}
```

Comment: You're overwriting the values without saving them, so the array ends up symmetrical around the center point

Comment: Why you don't use a temp array as buffer ?

Comment: Why avoid the `reverse`? You could clone the array first if you want to avoid changing the original array. E.g. `tab.slice(0).reverse()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is you're modifying the array at the same time you look into it, so when you get to the middle element it was already modified.

here's a manual execution of your script :

```
i | tab
0 | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
1 | [10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
2 | [10,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
3 | [10,9,8,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
4 | [10,9,8,7,5,6,7,8,9,10]
5 | [10,9,8,7,6,6,7,8,9,10]
6 | [10,9,8,7,6,6,7,8,9,10]
7 | ...
8 | ...
9 | ...
```

I think you can see the problem there

there are 2 ways to solve this problem:

```js
// either create a temp array to keep previous values
const reverseWithTmpArray = arr => {
  let tmp = [...arr]

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let num = (arr.length - i) - 1
    arr[i] = tmp[num]
  }  

  return arr
}

// or reverse the element by pairs 
const reverseByPairs = arr => {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++){
    let num = (arr.length - i) - 1

    let tmp = arr[i]
    arr[i] = arr[num]
    arr[num] = tmp

    // can also be written
    // [arr[i], arr[num]] = [arr[num], arr[i]]
    // using destructuring assignement
  }

  return arr
}

console.log(reverseWithTmpArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
console.log(reverseByPairs([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
```

**As I wrote them these 2 function mutate the input array, it can be rewritten to prevent this side effect**

[`doc of destructuring assignement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a temporary variable. Without that, you are just overwriting values like so.

```
Step 01: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Step 02: 10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Step 03: 10,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Step 04: 10,9,8,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Step 05: 10,9,8,7,5,6,7,8,9,10
Step 06: 10,9,8,7,6,6,7,8,9,10

// Now it will just take the values, but they are the same, so you are left with a mirrored array.

Step 07: 10,9,8,7,6,6,7,8,9,10
Step 08: 10,9,8,7,6,6,7,8,9,10
Step 09: 10,9,8,7,6,6,7,8,9,10
Step 10: 10,9,8,7,6,6,7,8,9,10
```

Do it like this instead:

```js
let tab = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    temp = []; // Create temp

let num=0

for(let i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
    num=(tab.length-i)-1
    temp[i]=tab[num] // Add to temp
}

tab = temp; // Assign temp to tab

console.log(tab)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tab = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11];

console.log("Before reverse:", tab);

for (var k = 0; k < parseInt(tab.length/2); k++) {
    var reverseIndex = (tab.length - 1) - k;
    var tmp = tab[reverseIndex];
    tab[reverseIndex] = tab[k];
    tab[k] = tmp; 
}

console.log("After reverse:", tab);
```